# Angular RouteGuard "A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value"

Tags: angular, rxjs, canactivate, angular-route-guards

I have a route guard that checks if a user has access to a resource, before proceeding.  After the subscription, I check if the user has access, and if not, redirect using `parseUrl` or return `true`.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PortfolioGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private resourceAccessService: ResourceAccessService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    // return this.resourceAccessService.checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id);
    this.resourceAccessService.checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id).subscribe((hasAccess) => {
      if (!hasAccess) {
        console.log('No access');
        return this.router.parseUrl('/');
      } else {
        console.log('access');
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This works if I only return the check, but I also want it to redirect based on that check.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PortfolioGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private resourceAccessService: ResourceAccessService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.resourceAccessService.checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id);
  }
}
```

What am I missing in the first block of code, should I be resolving the subscription from the service...

```js
checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id: number): Observable<boolean>  {
    const url = this.baseUrl + this.userResourceAccessUrl + '/' + + id + '/portfolio';
    return this.http.get<boolean>(url);
  }
```

Comment: Returning in a callback is **not** the same as returning in the method itself. Canonical: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/3001761.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use an Observable in Angular route guard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875294/how-to-use-an-observable-in-angular-route-guard)

Comment: @jonrsharpe - thanks, I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to return the Observable in the function:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean | UrlTree {
  const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    
  return this.resourceAccessService.checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id).pipe(
    map(hasAccess => {
      if (!hasAccess) {
        console.log('No access');
        this.router.parseUrl('/');
        return false
      } else {
        console.log('access');
        return true;
      }
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work either, still getting a syntax error.

Comment: a different one?

Answer (score 0):

The is issue is very obviously. You did not return anything in your function.

**Solution:**

1. add return to your function `canActivate`
2. remove subscribe and move all logic to map operator. Or you can use `tap`, `switchMap` operator. it depends on your context.

Instead of doing this:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PortfolioGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private resourceAccessService: ResourceAccessService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    // return this.resourceAccessService.checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id);
    this.resourceAccessService.checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id).subscribe((hasAccess) => {
      if (!hasAccess) {
        console.log('No access');
        return this.router.parseUrl('/');
      } else {
        console.log('access');
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

You can try using `pipe` and `map` operator.

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PortfolioGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private resourceAccessService: ResourceAccessService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean | UrlTree {
    const id = +route.paramMap.get('id');
    return this.resourceAccessService.checkUserAccessToPortfolio(id).pipe( map( hasAccess => {
      if(!hasAccess) {
        console.log('No access');
        this.router.parseUrl('/');
        return false
      } else {
        console.log('access');
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting *Argument of type 'Observable<unknown>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<boolean, boolean>'.
  Type 'Observable<unknown>' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable<boolean>): Observable<boolean>'*